# How to build release Hermes js bundle for React Native project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

I need to generate a js bundle for the React native project which uses Hermes.

With react native CLI I can only generate non-hermes bundle `npx react-native bundle`

What should I trigger to generate Hermes bundle separately?